# При подключении QStyledItemDelegate QTreeView перестает отображать данные модели

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Мне необходимо переопределить редактор для определенных элементов в QTreeView. Понаследовался от QStyledItemDelegate. Метод paint() не переопределял. Создаю делегат, вешаю его на QTreeView:

```
 MyDelegate delegate;
 ui->treeView->setItemDelegate(&delegate);
```

QTreeView перестал отображать данные модели. Переопределяю метод `paint()` делегата:

```
void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
                            const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                            const QModelIndex &index) const
{
  QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter,option,index);
}
```

Становлюсь на него отладчиком - метод не вызывается никогда. В чем может быть причина такого поведения?

Модель загружается из файла, после загрузки вызывается:

```
QVector<int> roles;
roles << Qt::DisplayRole << Qt::EditRole;
emit dataChanged(QModelIndex(),QModelIndex(),roles);
```

Если убрать делегат - всё работает.

Comment: Попробуйте создать делегат в куче, через `new`. По Вашему коду скорее всего получается, что делегат уничтожается невовремя.

Comment: @alexis031182, большое спасибо, вы правы, делегат создается в конструкторе формы, и, само-собой, при выходе из функции уничтожается. Создал его в куче - проблема ушла. Подскажите ещё, нужно ли явно вызывать `delete` делегата, если я указал ему `parent`?

Comment: Если указали родителя, то нет. Главное иметь в виду, что при установке делегата во вьюху, последняя не становится его родителем и ранее установленный делегат, если таковой был, не уничтожает, лишь заменяя его новым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что делегат создается на стеке и при выходе из функции (конструктора судя по коду), где выполняется настройка QTreeView, объект делегата удаляется. Решение очень простое, нужно создавать делегата в куче:

```
MyDelegate * delegate = new MyDelegate(this);
ui->treeView->setItemDelegate(delegate);
```

С делегатами есть еще одна тонкость. Функции подобные [setItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate) (а их несколько видов для: отдельных ячеек, строк, столбцов) не [устанавливают владельцем](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html) целевое представление, как это делается с виджетами например, и не удаляют старый делегат. Они просто переводят указатель на новый делегат, так что за удалением ненужных делегатов нужно отдельно следить, чтобы не было утечек.

Ну и, уж если пошла такая пьянка, то делегаты нелья разшаривать между несколькими представлениями.